# Ensuring that an entered name doesn’t end with a space

Tags: javascript

I am trying to get it so that if I type in a name that ends with a space, the textfield will go red. Most of the code works its just one method does not seem to be working.

The issue must be somewhere in the last index part?

```
var NamePass = true;

function ValidateName() {
    var BlankPass = true;
    var GreaterThan6Pass = true;
    var FirstBlankPass = true;
    var BlankMiddleName = true;

    if (document.getElementById('Name').value == "") {
        BlankPass = false;
    }

    var Size = document.getElementById('Name').value.length;
    console.log("Size = " + Size);

    if (Size < 7) {
        GreaterThan6Pass = false;
    }

    if (document.getElementById('Name').value.substring(0, 1) == " ") {
        FirstBlankPass = false;
    }

    var LastIndex = document.getElementById('Name').value.lastIndexOf();

    if (document.getElementById('Name').value.substring((LastIndex - 1), 1) == " ") {
        FirstBlankPass = false;
    }

    string = document.getElementById('Name').value;
    chars = string.split(' ');
    if (chars.length > 1) {} else
        BlankMiddleName = false;

    if (BlankPass == false || GreaterThan6Pass == false || FirstBlankPass == false || BlankMiddleName == false) {
        console.log("BlankPass = " + BlankPass);
        console.log("GreaterThan6Pass = " + GreaterThan6Pass);
        console.log("FirstBlankPass = " + FirstBlankPass);
        console.log("BlankMiddleName = " + BlankMiddleName);
        NamePass = false;
        document.getElementById('Name').style.background = "red";
    } else {
        document.getElementById('Name').style.background = "white";
    }
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/UTtxA/10/

Comment: Please make sure to indent your code! If you could also try to provide a title that better describes your question in the future, it would be much appreciated.

Comment: "its just one method does not seem to be working." could you elaborate?

Comment: So what part of it exactly does not work as expected? Btw, please store `document.getElementById('Name')` and its value in variables!

Comment: The style of programming `if (chars.length > 1) {} else { doSomething(); }` I will *never* understand. Why, *why*, why, why, **why** do something so obfuscatory? Come on. Make it sensible: `if (chars.length === 1) { doSomething(); }`.

Comment: P.S. Someone be really evil and mention regular expressions! :)

Comment: You could do this in a very concise matter using regular expressions!

Comment: I'm evil xD. I think this problem could be reduced to **one** line with a regular expression. This is what regex are for... But validating names is bad practice anyway, lots of possibilities (endless I'd say). Just validate length.

Comment: @elclanrs Validating lengths alone is not enough either. Think of Japanese, Chinese or Korean where few characters already make up the whole name.

Comment: Btw. instead of disallowing spaces at the beginning and end of the text, it would be a better idea to just strip that whitespace.

Comment: @poke: Exactly -- and to that end, [`trim`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/Trim).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`lastIndexOf` gets the last index of a character, not the last index in a string. I think you meant to use `length` instead:

```
var lastIndex = document.getElementById('Name').value.length;
```

Another problem with that, though, is that `substring` takes a start and end index, not a start index and a substring length. You could use `substr` instead, but `charAt` is easier:

```
if (document.getElementById('Name').value.charAt(lastIndex - 1) == " ") {
    FirstBlankPass = false;
}
```

Now, for some general code improvement. Instead of starting with all your variables at `true` and conditionally setting them to `false`, just set them to the condition:

```
var NamePass = true;

function ValidateName() {
    var value = document.getElementById('Name').value;

    var BlankPass = value == "";
    var GreaterThan6Pass = value.length > 6;
    var FirstBlankPass = value.charAt(0) == " ";
    var LastBlankPass = value.charAt(value.length - 1) == " ";
    var BlankMiddleName = value.split(" ").length <= 1;

    if (BlankPass || GreaterThan6Pass || FirstBlankPass || LastBlankPass || BlankMiddleName) {
        console.log("BlankPass = " + BlankPass);
        console.log("GreaterThan6Pass = " + GreaterThan6Pass);
        console.log("FirstBlankPass = " + FirstBlankPass);
        console.log("BlankMiddleName = " + BlankMiddleName);
        NamePass = false;
        document.getElementById('Name').style.background = "red";
    } else {
        document.getElementById('Name').style.background = "white";
    }
}
```

A couple more points of note:

- It’s probably a good idea to use `camelCase` variable names instead of `PascalCase` ones, the latter usually being reserved for constructors
- `blah == false` should really be written as `!blah`
- An empty `if` followed by an `else` can also be replaced with `if (!someCondition)`
- That function looks like it should return `true` or `false`, not set the global variable `NamePass`

Penultimately, you can sum this all up in one regular expression, but if you intend to provide more specific error messages to the user based on what’s actually wrong, then I wouldn’t do that.

```
function validateName() {
    return /^(?=.{6})(\S+(\s|$)){2,}$/.test(document.getElementById('name').value);
}
```

And finally — please keep in mind that not everyone has a middle name, or even a name longer than 6 characters, as @poke points out.

Comment: wow I feel like iv'e discovered classes again for the first time. That you for taking the time to explain it and showing how to improve. Knowing now that you can take a value from the html and be able to it makes better sense. Thanks!

Comment: Im trying to get it so 'nnnb nnnn' would be accepted. a space at front is not allowed and the same for the back. But you must have one somewhere in the name

Comment: @Steven: Almost, but just take out the `var NamePass = ValidateName();` line and check it in the `submit` event to stop the form from being submitted.

Comment: the submit event as in when I am finished and will have a submit button?

Comment: @Steven: Yep! `return false` from the submit handler of the form if `validateName()` returns `false`.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/UTtxA/17/
var BlankMiddleName = value.split(" ").length <= 1;
Just need how to get the find a ' ' inbetween the first and last chars and only one, if more than 1 or 0 show up when its invalid

Comment: @Steven: Oh, so you *want* there to be no middle name? Then it would be `value.split(" ").length == 2`.

Comment: No just any string longer than 6 characters that has a space somewhere other than the start or end
Valid:"aaaaa bbbb" "abe boo"
Invalid: "a " " a" invalid = aaaaaa valid = aaaa aa

Comment: @Steven: Okay, so `value.split(" ").length <= 1` should already be right. Your other checks take care of leading and trailing spaces. I forgot to add the one for trailing spaces to the big `if`, though — see [the edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/16328135/revisions).

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/29274/discussion-between-steven-and-rynah)